# Java scanner and int doesn't display age

Tags: java, variables

How can I subtract the birth year and current year to display age?

```
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String birth_year;

    System.out.print("Enter your the year you were born: ");
    birth_year = user_input.next();

    int age, current_year = 2016;
    age = current_year - birth_year;

    System.out.println("Your age is "+age);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `user_input.nextInt()` to read integer values, you can't substract String and int:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
int birth_year;

System.out.print("Enter your the year you were born: ");
birth_year = user_input.nextInt();

int age, current_year = 2016;
age = current_year - birth_year;

System.out.println("Your age is "+age)
```

Comment: @Zell Please mark the answer as approved if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this also

```
    LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(YEAR, MONTH, DAY);
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    int age = Period.between(birthdate, now).getYears();
```

Comment: That's new to me! Thanks for sharing some knowledge. I'm new to coding!